How to forward logs from Fluentbit to OpenObserve hosted on Azure Container App
I've deployed fluentbit to Azure Container Registry and then hosted it into an Azure Container App (ACA). I also did the same for OpenObserve and now I have Ingres enabled for the OpenObserve ACA and should receive traffic from the internet.
I want to make Fluentbit forward logs (dummy logs) to OpenObserve for analyzing them.
Here is my Dockerfile:
FROM cr.fluentbit.io/fluent/fluent-bit:3.0.3

COPY fluent-bit.conf /fluent-bit/etc/

where fluent-bit.conf input and output sections are:
[INPUT]
    NAME   dummy
    Dummy  { "log": "2022-07-16 02:44:09 [main] INFO  c.c.app.config.LogUtil - (()){\"type\":\"messageLog\", \"status\":\"success\", appName:\"appConfigService\""}
    Tag    test_log
    interval_sec 5

[OUTPUT]
    name http
    match *
    URI /api/default/my_stream/_json
    Host http://<openobserve-azure-container-app-url>
    Port 5080
    tls Off
    Format json
    Json_date_key    _timestamp
    Json_date_format iso8601
    HTTP_User <email>
    HTTP_Passwd <password>
    compress gzip

I get this error:
no upstream connections available to <openobserve-azure-container-app-url
in the log stream for the OpenObserve ACA.
Is there an issue with my configuration file for Fluentbit? Or is there a misconiguration in my Azure containers?
